# Woocommerce send and receive XML through HTTP request

Tags: xml, http, request

I'm creating an ecommerce store and it has to communicate with the billing software, which is totally independent and works on another server. That communication is made my XML through HTTP requests.

The communication is bilateral, shopping and stock information goes to the billing software and new stocks goes from the billing into Woocommerce.

The guys from the billing software gave me some information about the tags I can use and some examples of these communications and they're quite simple.

I don't have much experience on this, I've been checking the documentation for it but could use some help. What's the best way to create this requests, either for sending and receiving? Do I need to create a plugin or can I just implement new functions for it? From the billing server, it's already prepared to receive and send this information. I just need to create the request in WordPress.

Thank you!

Comment: What language?  Got any code started?

Comment: This is for Wordpress + Woocommerce so it'll be PHP. No, not yet... Basically I need to know where to start and some guidelines... :(

Comment: i missed that bit where you said woocommerce.  maybe tag question with PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's already a plugin for exporting:

http://www.woothemes.com/products/customerorder-xml-export-suite/

but I also need to receive communication from the remote server with new information such as new arrivals, new stock quantities, new clients, etc...